# Problem with Magento. Error on site

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, sql

I am having an issue with my Magento store. Below is the error I am getting when I go to the site. Can anyone please help?

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42
    [file:protected] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 234
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                    [line] => 300
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 479
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 238
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CREATE TABLE `adminnotification_inbox` (
  `notification_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Notification id',
  `severity` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Problem type',
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Create date',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title',
  `description` text NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `url` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Url',
  `is_read` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification read',
  `is_remove` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification might be removed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_SEVERITY` (`severity`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_READ` (`is_read`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_REMOVE` (`is_remove`)
) COMMENT='Adminnotification Inbox' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 419
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CREATE TABLE `adminnotification_inbox` (
  `notification_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Notification id',
  `severity` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Problem type',
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Create date',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title',
  `description` text NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `url` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Url',
  `is_read` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification read',
  `is_remove` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification might be removed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_SEVERITY` (`severity`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_READ` (`is_read`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_REMOVE` (`is_remove`)
) COMMENT='Adminnotification Inbox' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 2039
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => CREATE TABLE `adminnotification_inbox` (
  `notification_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Notification id',
  `severity` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Problem type',
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Create date',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title',
  `description` text NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `url` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Url',
  `is_read` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification read',
  `is_remove` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Flag if notification might be removed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`notification_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_SEVERITY` (`severity`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_READ` (`is_read`),
  INDEX `IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_REMOVE` (`is_remove`)
) COMMENT='Adminnotification Inbox' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/sql/adminnotification_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php
                    [line] => 81
                    [function] => createTable
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table Object
                                (
                                    [_tableName:protected] => adminnotification_inbox
                                    [_schemaName:protected] => 
                                    [_tableComment:protected] => Adminnotification Inbox
                                    [_columns:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [NOTIFICATION_ID] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => notification_id
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => integer
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => integer
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 1
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 1
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 1
                                                    [COMMENT] => Notification id
                                                )

                                            [SEVERITY] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => severity
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 1
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 0
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 1
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Problem type
                                                )

                                            [DATE_ADDED] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => date_added
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => timestamp
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 2
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => timestamp
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Create date
                                                )

                                            [TITLE] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => title
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => text
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 3
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => text
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 255
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Title
                                                )

                                            [DESCRIPTION] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => description
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => text
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 4
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => text
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 1
                                                    [LENGTH] => 64k
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Description
                                                )

                                            [URL] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => url
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => text
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 5
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => text
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 1
                                                    [LENGTH] => 255
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Url
                                                )

                                            [IS_READ] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => is_read
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 6
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 0
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 1
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Flag if notification read
                                                )

                                            [IS_REMOVE] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [COLUMN_NAME] => is_remove
                                                    [COLUMN_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [COLUMN_POSITION] => 7
                                                    [DATA_TYPE] => smallint
                                                    [DEFAULT] => 0
                                                    [NULLABLE] => 
                                                    [LENGTH] => 
                                                    [SCALE] => 
                                                    [PRECISION] => 
                                                    [UNSIGNED] => 1
                                                    [PRIMARY] => 
                                                    [PRIMARY_POSITION] => 0
                                                    [IDENTITY] => 
                                                    [COMMENT] => Flag if notification might be removed
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [_indexes:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_SEVERITY] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [INDEX_NAME] => IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_SEVERITY
                                                    [COLUMNS] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [SEVERITY] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [NAME] => severity
                                                                    [SIZE] => 
                                                                    [POSITION] => 0
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [TYPE] => index
                                                )

                                            [IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_READ] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [INDEX_NAME] => IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_READ
                                                    [COLUMNS] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [IS_READ] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [NAME] => is_read
                                                                    [SIZE] => 
                                                                    [POSITION] => 0
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [TYPE] => index
                                                )

                                            [IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_REMOVE] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [INDEX_NAME] => IDX_ADMINNOTIFICATION_INBOX_IS_REMOVE
                                                    [COLUMNS] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [IS_REMOVE] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [NAME] => is_remove
                                                                    [SIZE] => 
                                                                    [POSITION] => 0
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [TYPE] => index
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [_foreignKeys:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_options:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => INNODB
                                            [charset] => utf8
                                            [collate] => utf8_general_ci
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 624
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/sql/adminnotification_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php
                        )

                    [function] => include
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 421
                    [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => install
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 1.6.0.0
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 327
                    [function] => _installResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1.6.0.0
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 235
                    [function] => applyUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 417
                    [function] => applyAllUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 343
                    [function] => _initModules
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app/Mage.php
                    [line] => 683
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [scope_code] => 
                                    [scope_type] => store
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/index.php
                    [line] => 86
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => store
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => PDOException Object
        (
            [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'adminnotification_inbox' already exists
            [string:Exception:private] => 
            [code:protected] => 42S01
            [file:protected] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
            [line:protected] => 228
            [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
                            [line] => 228
                            [function] => execute
                            [class] => PDOStatement
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                            [line] => 110
                            [function] => _execute
                            [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                            [line] => 300
                            [function] => _execute
                            [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                            [type] => ->
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

Comment: Have you been trying to upgrade or install a module? If so you may need to re-install or remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to reference a table that already exists. I would recommend exporting adminnotification_inbox, then deleting that table from your database. Refresh the page and then let the module do its thing (which should recreate the table). Once the table has been recreated by the module import your backed up data back into it.